# Best approach in dealing with data inputs from dynamic sub forms in .NET MVC app

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, model-binding

I'm relatively new to .NET MVC and have been struggling with an web app I'm working on. In sum, this app consists of a form, the main part which inputs the customer's name, and then there's a button to add a child. When this button is clicked, a sub form appears via a partial view. I'm not sure what to do with the data yet when the save button on the sub form is clicked yet (but the sub form will collapse, accordion style on the HTML side), but the gist is that a customer can add one or many child sub forms to input their child(ren)'s names and ages.

What is the best way to handle the inputs on these forms? I spoke w/ some coworkers and they seemed unsure. One suggested that I first save the 'parent' form to the data base and then within each sub-form (child), when the save button is click, send those onto the database as well, using the parent Id to connect them. Someone else suggested using Vue for this. What would YOU suggest in terms of model-binding or sending the data back to the controller?

First the view model for the form looks like this:

```
namespace ModelBindingObjects.ViewModel
{
    public class ParentVM
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public List<ChildVM> Children { get; set; }
    }

public class ChildVM
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public int Age { get; set; }
    }

}
```

For the db side, the models look like this:

```
    public partial class Parent
    {
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(50)]
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

 public partial class Child
    {
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public int ParentId { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(50)]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public int Age { get; set; }
```

The view looks like this

```
@model ModelBindingObjects.ViewModel.ParentVM
<h3>A Sample Form</h3>
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="form-row">
                <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                    @Html.LabelFor(x => x.Name, new { @class = "required" })
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Name, new { @class = "form-control" })
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6">

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                <div class="addChildren">
                    <h5 class="topspacing-med btmspacing-med">Your Child(ren) Details</h5>
                    <div class="displayChildForm">
                        @*@Html.Partial("_AddChild", new ViewDataDictionary()
                            {
                                TemplateInfo = new TemplateInfo()
                                { HtmlFieldPrefix = "Test" }
                            })*@
                    </div>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-secondary btn-sm btn-block btmspacing-med" id="addChild">Add New Child</button>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-md-6"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
}


@section scripts {
    <script type="text/javascript">

       var hideButtons = function () {
            $("#addChild").hide();
        };

        $("#saveChild").click(function () {
            console.log("testing");
            $(".panel-body").hide();
        });

        $("#addChild").click(function () {
            $.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("RenderAddChildForm", "Home")',
                dataType: "html",
                type: 'GET',
                success: function (result) {
                    $('.displayChildForm').append(result);
                    hideButtons();
                },
                error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                    console.log(xhr.status);
                    console.log(thrownError);
                },

            });
        });


    </script>
```

Then the partial view ...

```
@model ModelBindingObjects.ViewModel.ChildVM

    <div class="panel panel-primary">
        <div class="panel-heading"><h5>Add A Child</h5></div>
        <div class="panel-body">
            <div class="form-group row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <input type="hidden" name="products.Index" value="test" />
                    @*@Html.LabelFor(x => x.Name)
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Name, new { @class = "form-control" })*@
                    <input type="text" name="[test].Name" value="Delaney" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <input type="text" name="[test].Age" value="12" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="btn-group float-right mt-2" role="group">
                <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm btn-block" type="submit" id="saveChild">Save</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

and at great last, the good old controller:

```
namespace ModelBindingObjects.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        private string PartialViewPath(string name)
        {
            return $"~/Views/Partials/{name}.cshtml";
        }

        // GET: Home
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult RenderAddChildForm()
        {
            return PartialView(PartialViewPath("_AddChild"));
        }
    }



}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just model bind to an ICollection property on the model

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding?view=aspnetcore-2.2#collections

an oldie but a goldie: https://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx/

You might find some libraries of mine helpful for this kind of thing also.

https://github.com/mcintyre321/FormFactory
https://github.com/mcintyre321/AspNetCoreJTokenModelBinder

Comment: Thanks! The combination of the haacked link you posted in addition to this one http://www.binaryintellect.net/articles/b1e0b153-47f4-4b29-8583-958aa22d9284.aspx helped me get this code up and running. Much easier than I anticipated.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the complexity of the page flow, how familiar you're with Vue, and if there is a separate edit page or you want to support edit/delete within the same page. If all it does is save children, then you can easily do that with AJAX requests without introducing Vue.

One approach is to separate the two operations, so the user can't add a child unless they have added and saved the parent's data. On parent form save success, return the saved parentId, and disable the button. For each subform, when the user clicks "save child", send {parentId, childVm}.

Another approach is to have only one save button for the entire page i.e. each child doesn't get their own save button. The `displayChildForm` div acts as a collection of inputs with a single "add child" button that creates more children partial views and appends them to itself. When the user clicks the page's save button, you send {parentVm, childVmCollection[]}.

You can mix both approaches, so you end up with a "save parent" button, and a single "save/edit children" button within the `displayChildForm` div. On clicking save children button, you send {parentId, childVmCollection[]}.

Comment: thank you! I got this up and working using a collection of inputs w/ a single button. This reference helped me envision how the code should look: http://www.binaryintellect.net/articles/b1e0b153-47f4-4b29-8583-958aa22d9284.aspx although I can imagine with Vue, this would be a much more easier task.